# LinqToSql - An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I'm using LinqToSql for a mvc web application. If lots of people hit the web app at roughly the same time, I'm seeing an `An item with the same key has already been added.` error. The stack for this error looks like:

```
[ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.]
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) +12673712
   System.Data.Linq.DataContext.GetTable(MetaTable metaTable) +286
   System.Data.Linq.DataContext.GetTable() +100
   CableSense.Domain.Repository.Concrete.RoleRepository.GetRolesForUser(String userName) in c:\BuildAgent\work\271278ff356daf1\CableSense.Domain\Repository\Concrete\RoleRepository.cs:84
```

This *only* happens from my RoleRrovider class, which is a custom implementation of the .net RoleProvider. In there, my ctor gets a repository from Ninject like this:

```
    public CustomRoleProvider()
    {
        _roleRepository = NinjectMVC3.Resolve<IRoleRepository>();
    }
```

The method that errors:

```
    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        return _roleRepository.GetRolesForUser(username);
    }
```

In my repo is nothing but a linq query which returns the data - the repo instantiates a context internally, nothing is static or shared.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if Ninject has the option to do this, but it should return a new isntance of the required context every time you call resolve.

This is caused by the fact that the EF contexts are not thread safe.

For instance, I use Castle.Windsor as my IoC of choice and it has a LifeStyle option, setting it to Transient instead of Singleton (which is the default) gets the desired behaviour.

Comment: +1 The context is supposed to represent a unit of work, so it doesn't make sense for it to be shared between threads

Answer (score 0):

```
private object _lockHandle=new object();

 public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
lock(_lockHandle){
        return _roleRepository.GetRolesForUser(username);
}
    }
```